# Getting NullPointerException while running the simple testNG script

Tags: java, testng

Code as below:

```
Public class sample {
  @Test
  Public void test() {
    Syso("hi");
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. What have you done to solve this problem? Have you done a google search at all? Can you provide any stacktrace? What do your config files look like?

Comment: What is Syso? An user-defined class? Can you share the code of its constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` in the given code is because of the typo in the `syso` statement. The correct statement should be `System.out.println()` instead of `syso()`.

The corrected code should look like:

```
public class Sample {
@Test
public void test() {
System.out.println("hi");
}
}
```

Once you make the correction, you should be able to run the test case without getting the `NullPointerException`.

It is important to use proper coding conventions and follow best practices while writing test cases. This helps in avoiding common errors and makes the code more readable and maintainable. You can refer to resources like the Java coding conventions by Oracle (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-introduction.html) for guidance on writing clean and efficient code in Java.